# How to add more than 3 items to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

```
Dictionary<string, string, bool> loginUserData = new Dictionary<string, string, bool>(); 
loginUserData.Add("max", "123", true);
```

results in this error:

> Using the generic type 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type argument

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string, bool>` is invalid, at least with the framework's `Dictionary` class, do you mean `Dictionary<string, (string, bool)>`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? A Dictionary maps keys (of a type) to values (of a type).

Comment: You may use a Tuple Tuple<T1,T2,T3>: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @vc74 You should mention that you are referring to [Tuple type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) with `(string, bool)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary is a key/value collection, you can have only one type for the key and another for the value, so for your case, you can use a Tuple for your value presentation

```
Dictionary<string, (string, bool)> loginUserData = new Dictionary<string, (string, bool)>(); 
loginUserData.Add("max", ("123", true));
```

Or else, If you don't need a key for your further needs, try to use a tuple with three arguments.

Comment: thank you! it works. Now if I wanna do something like `if (!loginUserData[.ContainsKey(Console.ReadLine()))` how can I access the strings? (it's `loginUserData.Add(("max", "mustermann"), false);` btw

Comment: First, your Add is not correct, you should put this, 
```C#
loginUserData.Add("max", ("mustermann", false)), 
```
you can access the name anonymously 
```C#
loginUserData["max"].item1
```
, or you can use **named tuple** instead